# Get the IPv6 routing table from a windows pc with WS-Management

Tags: windows, wmi, winrm

I have to get the IPv6 routing table from a windows pc with WS-Management. I'm using wsman for the client on linux. I found the Win32_IP4RouteTable WMI class fot IPv4, but it looks like WMI doesn't support IPv6. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [I don't think you can do this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822883%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it finally, the suitable class is MSFT_NetRoute in the \root\StandardCimv2 namespace, but it only exists since Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012. It contains both IPv4 and IPv6 entries.